# Barchart percentage subgroups

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 15 metrics (columns) from a csv. 1 metric is called `Cancer`

This is what the column in the dataset looks like

```
Cancer:  yes no yes no
```

I just would like to have a barchart (stacked and normal) showing the percentages yes and no from Cancer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

```
df <- data.frame(Cancer = c("yes", "yes", rep("no", 8)))
```

2.A solution using `ggplot2` and `scales`

If you only need the summaries for the plot we can use ggplot directly:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Cancer)) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  labs(x="Cancer", y="Relative frequency [%]")
```

[image]

Comment: This one works too thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should do the desired stacked plot using `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x="", fill = Cancer))+
  #Do the bar plot scaled to 1
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  #Change the y axis labels as percent
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image: stacked plot]

Comment: Thanks it works. Can you also make a simple table of the same with percentages yes/no cancer? But I am making a yes/no overview from different subgroups (filter: age 50-54, agebirthfirstchild <30). So all subgroups yes/no percentages in one table

Comment: How to do the same when I different variables with sub categories? in them such as if i have gender contains male female , disease contains multiple sub-types etc